# Django model field order

Tags: django, django-models

How can I access the ordered list of model fields? Because `model_instance._meta.fields` returns fields without m2m, but in admin view the fields order exactly same as they are defined in class. 
(like edit form on admin site) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
sorted(model_instance._meta.fields + model_instance._meta.many_to_many,
       key=lambda x:x.creation_counter)
```

If M2M fields are defined after normal fields, you could use `fields + many_to_many` directly since both of them are already in the declaration ordering.

*update*

If you prefer to use `operator.attrgetter()` instead of `lambda`, it's OK, the performance difference is trivial. But `attrgetter` is not guranteed to be faster:

```
In[1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
In[2]: fields = User._meta.fields + User._meta.many_to_many
In[3]: %timeit sorted(fields, key=lambda x:x.creation_counter)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.47 us per loop

In[4]: from operator import attrgetter
In[5]: %timeit sorted(fields, key=attrgetter('creation_counter'))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.17 us per loop

In[6]: ag=attrgetter('creation_counter')
In[7]: %timeit sorted(fields, key=ag)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.68 us per loop
```

Comment: Thank you. This will be a little faster : <code>sorted(new_instance._meta.fields + new_instance._meta.many_to_many, key=itemgetter('creation_counter'))

Comment: @Andrewshkovskii Perhaps you mean `attrgetter`, it's convenient for fetching multiple attributes, but not guaranteed to be faster. see the update